# Get facebook friends list

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know I can get my friend list using `me/friends`. But what I need is get friend list of any user who made their friend list public. For example say my friend's facebook Id is 'XXXXX'. When I tried `[fbAgent requestWithGraphPath:@"XXXXX/" andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys] andDelegate:self];` I got my friends name and some details. Also I got something when tried `[fbAgent requestWithGraphPath:@"XXXXX/feed" andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys] andDelegate:self];`.But I failed to get friend list when `[fbAgent requestWithGraphPath:@"XXXXX/friends" andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys] andDelegate:self];` it threw

`2 : <CFString 0x6854230 [0x1473b38]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x6854370 [0x1473b38]>{contents = "FacebookApiException"}
    3 : <CFString 0x6854310 [0x1473b38]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x68542c0 [0x1473b38]>{contents = "Unsupported operation"}
    6 : <CFString 0x6847c60 [0x1473b38]>{contents = "code"} = 100`

So how can I get friend list of any user. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can only fetch friend list of loggedin user. Revealing you the friend list of any user results in revealing all their ids which Facebook never supports.